# How to display manytomany field in django admin with a related model in a user-friendly way?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I'm struggling to display a manytomany field in the admin with the related model in a user-friendly manner. The project is already up and running so adding a through table is not preferred.

The set-up is something along these lines;

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_member_of_organization = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, blank=True, verbose_name=_("is member of organization(s)"), related_name='orgmembers')


class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name=_("organization name"))
```

the only reasonable way I manage to display the related users with organization admin is via a TabularInline

```
admin.py

class UserOrgAdminInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User.is_admin_for_organization.through
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Organization)
class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (UserOrgAdminInLine,)
```

However, looking up users is not convenient as soon as their number increases. I would like something similar to `filer_horizontal` but I am not sure how to include it directly in the OrganizationAdmin admin class. Furthermore, I am using fieldsets (which I believe should have no special rules or syntax to it compared to ordinary `fields =` .

One little subquestion - in the tabular inline, when I use only `model = User` django throws an error that there is no foreign key to it, but when I use the additional `.is_admin_for_organization.through` it works, but there is no through table and I though that this work just in that case. Why is that?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
class UserOrgAdminInLine
raw_id_fields = ("is_member_of_organization",)
```